# How to prevent closing html tag from automatically appearing upon having initiated by Jquery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jsp file contains -

```
<table class="container"></table>
```

JS file does -

```
$('.container').append('<thead><tr><th>Name</th>');     //step 1
/* some other events */
$('.container').append('<th>Date</th></thead></tr>');   //step 3
```

the `<thead>` and `<tr>` tags get closed, i.e. get appended with  automatically after step one before I can actually reach step 3 and close them myself. 
It is necessary for me to calculate the next heading dynamically which is why some other steps need to occue before I create the next heading. 
Is there any way by which I can prevent those tags from closing upon the end of step 1 and later close them myself.

Answer (score 3):

Use a single `.append()` in your code. Declare a variable and keep on adding the data required to it. Then append that variable to "container" at the end. Use minimum DOM manipulation wherever possible.

For example:

```
Var content = '<thead><tr><th>Name</th>';
//Do your manipulation and add more data to "content"
content = content + '<th>Date</th></thead></tr>';
```

Finally append the variable in container:

```
$('.container').append(content);
```

Comment: I think a little example would be helpful.

Comment: thank you, it worked. It should have come to my mind. Now I see, it was such an obvious way.. Thanks..

Comment: You are most welcome. Do accept the answer if you found it useful :)